# Change "class" to "struct"

Tags: c++, c

I need to change the struct "class" to "struct normal" to make it easy to read the source code. It's possible, change "class" in the beginning of the code to "struct" in the source code in *[Program to create a queue using dynamic memory allocation](http://www.syntax-example.com/Code/create-queue-dynamic-memory-allocation-973.aspx)*.

Comment: To whoever voted this up - why did you do that?

Comment: One can forgive you for grammatically and stylistically bad English, but I am afraid your English is just impossible to understand... Try again

Comment: Does your editor have a "Find and Replace" feature?

Comment: Be aware that changing from `struct` to `class` changes the default visibility from *public* to *private*.  Also, why is `class` more readable than `struct`?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to understand what exactly your question is. A `struct` in C++ is the same as a `class`, except that members are by default `public` instead of `private`.

If you have a `struct` and you want to make it a `class`, you can do that like this:

```
struct Thing {
  // ...
};

// Change this to:
class Thing {
public:
  // ...
};
```

Or, the other way around, a `class` to a `struct`:

```
class Thing {
  // ...
};

// Change this to:
struct Thing {
private:
  // ...
};
```

I don't see, however, how one would be "more readable" than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Change class to struct =

```
1) Find a "Find and Replace" button in your IDE or text editor
2) In Find What field enter class
3) In Replace With field enter struct
4) click Replace All
```

Yeah this is a crappy answer, but so is the question :)

Comment: Oh I think this the most appropriate answer! ;)

Comment: Before using this technique, the `struct`s need to be reviewed for any `public`, `protected` or `private` keywords.  Also, changing from `struct` to `class` changes the default accessibility, so a global replace is not warranted.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, indeed, apart from that one must be cautious not to replace class  keyword in template parameters.:)